# Как выравнять текст

Tags: html, css, frontend

Делаю сайт по готовому шаблону и вот такая проблема.

Должно быть так:
[image]
При изменении текста получается так:
[image]

```css
.event_txt {
  padding-top: 73px;
  padding-bottom: 73px;
}

.pricing_area {
  background-image: url(images/pricing_bg.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.pricing_area:before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(201, 50, 50, 0.95);
}

.single_pricing_block {
  background: #c93232;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.40);
  padding: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.pricing_title h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
  line-height: 37px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.pricing_left,
.pricing_right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.pricing_title {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.event_info ul li {
  color: #ebebeb;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.event_info span::after {
  content: ":";
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.pricing_right {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.price {
  padding: 58px 55px 45px;
  background: #222;
  text-align: center;
}

.price p {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 37px;
}

.price span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 37px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: block;
  color: #ababab;
}

.price_detail {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.pricing_right.al {
  margin: 0;
}

.pricing_right.fr {
  margin-left: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="single_pricing_block reveal animated" data-reveal-anim="fadeInLeftShort" data-anim-delay="0.3s">
  <div class="pricing_left">
    <div class="price_detail">
      <div class="pricing_title">
        <h4>New Year Eve Party</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="event_info">
        <ul>
          <li><span>Place</span>Town hall</li>
          <li><span>Time</span>5pm - 10pm</li>
          <li>buffet, lottery, magic etc</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Есть идея - засунуть эти 4 блока в тег `<table>`, который немного модифицировать. Могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flex:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.event_txt{
    padding-top: 73px;
    padding-bottom: 73px;
}
.pricing_area{
    background-image: url(images/pricing_bg.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
.pricing_area:before{
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(201,50,50,0.95);
}
.single_pricing_block{
    
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.pricing_title h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "roboto",sans-serif;
    line-height: 37px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.pricing_left, .pricing_right{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.event_info ul li {
    color: #ebebeb;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.event_info span::after {
    content: ":";
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.price{
    padding: 58px 55px 45px;
    background: #222;
    text-align: center;
}
.price p {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 37px;
}
.price span{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 37px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    color: #ababab;
}
.price_detail{    
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pricing_right.al{
    margin: 0;
}
.pricing_right.fr{
    margin-left: 46px;
}

.single_pricing_block {
  width: 50%;
}

.pricing_left,
.pricing_right {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #c93232;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.40);
  padding: 3px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
}

.pricing_right {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}


.pricing_left .price_detail {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.pricing_right .price_detail {
  padding-right: 35px;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .wrap {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }
  
  .single_pricing_block {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .pricing_left,
  .pricing_right {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="single_pricing_block reveal animated" data-reveal-anim="fadeInLeftShort" data-anim-delay="0.3s">
    <div class="pricing_right">
      <div class="price">
        <p>
          100$
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="price_detail">
        <div class="pricing_title">
          <h4>New Year Eve Party</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="event_info">
          <ul>
            <li><span>Place</span>Town hall</li>
            <li><span>Time</span>5pm - 10pm</li>
            <li>buffet, lottery, magic etc</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="single_pricing_block reveal animated" data-reveal-anim="fadeInLeftShort" data-anim-delay="0.3s">
    <div class="pricing_left">
      <div class="price">
        <p>
          100$
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="price_detail">
        <div class="pricing_title">
          <h4>New Year Eve Party</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="event_info">
          <ul>
            <li><span>Place</span>Town hall</li>
            <li><span>Time</span>5pm - 10pm</li>
            <li>buffet, lottery, magic etc</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="single_pricing_block reveal animated" data-reveal-anim="fadeInLeftShort" data-anim-delay="0.3s">
    <div class="pricing_right">
      <div class="price">
        <p>
          100$
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="price_detail">
        <div class="pricing_title">
          <h4>New Year Eve Party</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="event_info">
          <ul>
            <li><span>Place</span>Town hall</li>
            <li><span>Time</span>5pm - 10pm</li>
            <li>buffet, lottery, magic etc</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="single_pricing_block reveal animated" data-reveal-anim="fadeInLeftShort" data-anim-delay="0.3s">
    <div class="pricing_left">
      <div class="price">
        <p>
          100$
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="price_detail">
        <div class="pricing_title">
          <h4>New Year Eve Party</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="event_info">
          <ul>
            <li><span>Place</span>Town hall</li>
            <li><span>Time</span>5pm - 10pm</li>
            <li>buffet, lottery, magic etc</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```